# Transfer Socket between process in .Net Core 2.0 (DuplicateAndClose alternatives)

Tags: sockets, .net-core

I am trying to convert my existing project from .Net Framework 4.6 to .Net Core 2.0. One of the task is to transfer socket to another process. I have failed to achieve this with [DuplicateAndClose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.duplicateandclose.aspx) due to lack of support in .Net Core.
What are the alternatives that can be used at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A comment in the source code of `DuplicateAndClose` on .Net Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/abae818/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs#L2120-L2123) says:

> On Windows, we cannot duplicate a socket that is bound to an IOCP.  In this implementation, we *only*
>   support IOCPs, so this will not work.
>
> On Unix, duplication of a socket into an arbitrary process is not supported at all.

I think this means there is effectively no way to transfer sockets between processes on .Net Core and you will have to use some other approach. How would that look like will depend on the protocol you're using and the reason for why you are transferring sockets in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. I did read that comment in the source code but that did not answer my question of alternative way thus I asked it here.
About why I am doing that, I do not want to overburden my main process thus I create an individual process for each sub task. Sometimes different sub tasks suffer due to one non responding task thus making separate processes addresses my cause. Moreover, my main processes used to crash/forced-close due to one of my non-responding sub tasks. I hope, I conveyed what I am trying to achieve. Possibly, now I will have to close this socket and create a new one?

Comment: Whether closing and reopening the socket will work depends on the protocol. Also, a non-responding sub-task should not harm the process it's running in, you should consider actually fixing the issue, instead of working around it by using multiple processes, if possible.

Comment: Well, it's a different scenario. We had to stick with it in production environment due to the nature of use-case. Anyways, I am open to discuss that in case you want to go ahead.